Unable to understand why i get total count of wb_user id in all job code in power bi?
i have two table all freelancer profile and job profile joined with one to many relation common field are wb_user id
all freelancer wb_user id connected to multiple job profile wb_user id
i have created two table visual
iam taking wb user id from all freelancer and job code from job profile
in one table i have counted wb_user id vs distinct count of job code
other table job code vs distinct count of wb_user id
first visual able to give correct value but second table provide total value to each job code
i just wants tenter image descriptiono know why i get total value in all job code?
here

Your relationship is one-way and so the many side is not filtering the one side, hence you are getting the all count.
You can use the CROSSFILTER function to help with this:
YourMeasure = 
  CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('YourTable'[Column]),
    CROSSFILTER('YourTable[wb_user], 'YourOtherTable'[wb_user], BOTH)
  )

Or you can update your relationship from One to Both direction.
